# Loading C++ dll in C# throws Access Memory Violation when running on 32 bit machine

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am trying to load a dll written in C++, I am using windows API GetProcAddress method to call the function from the dll, it works fine on my development machine which is 64 bit since I need to run the application on a 32 bit machine it throws 
**'An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in MarkEzd.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. '**

I have tried every debugging option but nothing worked, Any help much will be appreciated, below is my sample c# code which I am using to communicate with the dll.

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllpath);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
      public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hmodule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpname);
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
      public static extern IntPtr FreeLibrary(IntPtr hmodule);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
      private delegate int Initialize(string path);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
      private delegate int Close();
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
      private delegate int LoadTemplate(string templateName);

Program()
    {
        IntPtr loadDll      = LoadLibrary(@"MarkEzd.dll");
        IntPtr initial      = GetProcAddress(loadDll, "lmc1_Initial");
        Console.WriteLine(initial);
        IntPtr close        = GetProcAddress(loadDll, "lmc1_Close");
        Console.WriteLine(close);
        IntPtr loadtemplate = GetProcAddress(loadDll, "lmc1_LoadEzdFile");
        if (((int)loadDll > 0) && ((int)initial > 0))
            this.InitializeMarker(loadDll, initial, close, loadtemplate);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot initialize the given address");
    }
    private void InitializeMarker(IntPtr loadDll, IntPtr  initial, IntPtr close, IntPtr template)
    {
        Initialize ini  = (Initialize)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(initial, typeof(Initialize));   
         int result      = ini("folderpath");


        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```